# MongoDB error: ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend

When I follow writing MongoDB version 6.0 so my code have this error: ReferenceError: data is not defined. I do not know how to fix it because I am just a newbie and I watched it on Youtube. So help me to fix it how to run it success, please. Thank everyone!

This is my code in database.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const connectDatabase =( )=>{
     mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI).then(()=>{
         console.log(`Mongodb connected with server: ${data.connection.host}`);
     }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err)
     })
 }
module.exports = connectDatabase
```

And this is terminal notification:

```
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
Server is working on http://localhost:4000
ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at C:\Users\ngomi\Desktop\MERN Project\backend\config\database.js:8:55
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
```

Answer (score 0):

add `data` after `then`

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI).then((data)=>{
  console.log(`Mongodb connected with server: ${data.connection.host}`);
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err)
})
```